# How to convert a numeric variable to a string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text

```
A=rand(10)
B=find(A>98)
```

How do you have text saying "There were 2 elements found" where the 2 is general i.e. it isn't text, so that if I changed `B=find(A>90)` it would automatically no longer be 2.

Answer (score 7):

```
some_number = 2;
text_to_display = sprintf('There were %d elements found',some_number);
disp(text_to_display);
```

Also, if you wanted to count the number of elements greater than `98` in `A`, you should one of the following:

```
numel(find(A>98));
```

Or

```
sum(A>98);
```

[`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) is a very elegant way to display such data and it's quite easy for a person with a C/C++ background to start using it. If you're not comfortable with the format-specifier syntax (check out the link) then you can use:

```
text_to_display = ['There were ' num2str(some_number) ' elements found'];
```

But I would recommend `sprintf` :)

Comment: If you don't care about saving a string, you can skip the call to disp, by simply calling `fprintf` (and not saving any output) which will output to the display also. Note that you may wish to add `\n` to ensure a new line appears.

Comment: @Geoff - `disp` tacks the newline on for you.  Also, you can just do `disp(sprintf(...))` or `disp(['There were ' ...]) to avoid the temp variable.

Comment: @mtrw: disp adds three newlines, and thus wastes valuable screen real estate. Therfore, I'd go with fprintf unless you have to keep the string around.

Comment: @Jonas - I'd forgotten about that.  FWIW, in Octave `disp` uses up just one line.